# Get Id from a value in a controller in Symfony

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, controller

What I am trying to do is to **get an Id from a folder number**.
Both my Id and my folder number (folder number is unique) are in the same controller.

I get the folder number from a text input and I then need to redirect the user to a page /Id.

My question is how should I handle it ?

Do I need to create a method *getIdFromFolderNumber()* **in my controller** and then **call this function** in my JS function ?
Or maybe do I need to do **everything** in a JS function (I know I need a JS function since I will use an AJAX request to redirect my user and to get the value from the input).

I don't need the code or anything, I just want to know the method I need to use to understand how to do it. I've started working on a very big project and since I am a junior developer I am a bit lost.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any JS to achieve that. It's a simple form and redirection.

Once your form which gives you the number is submitted :

`$number = $form->get('number')->getData();`

Then you got your criteria for your doctrine request :

`$id = $yourEntityRepository->findBy(['number' => $number)])->getId();`

Now you have your ID for the redirection :

`return $this->redirectToRoute('entity_show', ['id' => $id]);`

IS that what you were looking for ?

Note : you don't need to store $number and $id as variables. It was only to make it clear. You can replace them by the actual requests where it's needed.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear regarding the use of JS. I needed to trigger to redirection onchange of the input, that's why I needed JS.
But I found a solution. What I did what make a GET request and return a JSON containing 'url' => '$url'.